# Not able to redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy an application on Tomcat. I am using Application Load Balancer. I have used AWS Certificate Manager and generated a certificate, have a domain like app.example.com and I can access my application via https://app.example.com.

However the app still accepts http requests. I need to force https.

Below are my application load balancer configurations.

Listeners

[image]

Processes

[image]

Rules

[image]

I have the same setting in another beanstalk and it works fine. What is wrong in here?

Comment: You didn't show the contents of the rule. But the path pattern doesn't make sense, neither does the fact that you have two rules. Shouldn't there be just one rule without any special pattern that is attached to the listener on port 80 and executes a redirect?

Comment: @CherryDT: Appreciate your input. i am not clear what you meant by the content of the rules. I did not use any configuration file, all done through the web console. So i clicked on "+ Add Rule" and applied the same data as you see above into its fields.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because rules have more settings than shown here. See this article for an example how correct https redirect rules in an ALB would look: https://mohitshrestha02.medium.com/redirect-http-and-www-requests-to-https-through-application-load-balancer-on-aws-ad11966c5218 - And the documentation for Beanstalk instead shows another method that _does_ use config files (which should be easier to deploy): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html